# CheckedListBox filter with a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, checkedlistbox

I'm new to this, so it may be a simple thing but I'm stuck on this from a couple of days. I'm trying to **implement** `Select All` functionality and filtering a CheckedListBox using a TextBox in my Form.
Something like that of Excel filter. Similar to the image below:

[image: excel filter]

I'm populating the CheckedListBox with an array. The array capacity keeps changing depending on the number of items. It may be 10 or 20 or above 50.

What I've tried:

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) == true)
            SelectDeselectAll(true);
        else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) == false)
            SelectDeselectAll(false);
        //when select all is checked, and I uncheck a item in the list, uncheck select all and the item
        else //if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) == true && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) )
            SelectDeselectAll(null);
    }

    private void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filter_param = SearchBox.Text.ToUpper();
        var item = checkedListBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
        List<string> filteredItems = item.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith(filter_param));

        checkedListBox1.DataSource = filteredItems;

        // if all values removed, bind the original full list again
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchBox.Text))
        {
            checkedListBox1.DataSource = cboxAr;
        }
    }

    private void SelectDeselectAll(bool? v)
    {
        if (v == true)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
        else if (v == false)
            checkedListBox1.ClearSelected();
        else if (v == null)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> notChecked = (from int item in checkedListBox1.Items
                                           where !checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Contains(item)
                                           select item);

            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) == true)
            {
                SelectDeselectAll(false); 
                foreach (int j in notChecked)
                    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(j, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

**After debug**: Select all functionality is working well. But when I filter and try to select the filtered items, the `if` part is implemented and the control flows to `SelectDeselectAll(true)`.

Also, what's not working is: 
when I select all and than uncheck one of the items in the list, it doesn't work out.

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Can anyone please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try something a bit more simple:

```
    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(0));
            }
        }
        else //if you unchecked one of the other checkbox when select all is checked, then the select all is unchecked 
        {
            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(0) == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> filtered= cboxAr.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.ToUpper().Contains(SearchBox.Text.ToUpper()))
            .ToList();

        checkedListBox1.DataSource = filtered;
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchBox.Text))
        {
            checkedListBox1.DataSource = cboxAr;
        }
    }
```

make sure to change the event to SelectedValueChanged,
and also make the DoubleClick event to call this event also.

I recommend to add these lines when you assign initial values to  the CheckBoxList:

```
checkedListBox1.SelectedValueChanged -= checkedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
checkedListBox1.DataSource = cboxAr;
checkedListBox1.SelectedValueChanged += checkedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
```

because when assiging data to datasource  the value changes too and the event occurs

so you should have 4 references to this event in total.
[image]

Comment: Its the same as the op has posted.

Comment: I'm sorry that was a mistake, I uploaded a working version  @AshishSrivastava

Comment: @DorLugasi Thank you for the answer. But can you please tell me where to place your recommended codes exactly?

Comment: Also When I click `select all` and than uncheck any one of the values in the `checkedlistbox`, `select all` option is still checked. And when I try to manually uncheck `select all`, everything is unchecked.

Comment: @Raj, you place the recommended code whenever you assign values to the checkbox list. and if you use my code this shouldn't happen because it unselect all

Comment: @DorLugasi Your code works fine with select and unselect all. But in the select all mode if I uncheck any one value in the list, then why doesn't it uncheck the `select all` check box?

Comment: @Raj you are right, I didn't add this functionality, i will edit my answer for you

Comment: @Raj, I've edited my answer for you, just added another if, on the event change, it would be best if you use the checkOnClick property instead of doubleClick event

Comment: @DorLugasi Cool. That works smooth. But I'm sorry I'm still not clear on the checkOnClick or DoubleClick event. why do I need them?

Comment: CheckOnClick = true makes the checkbox change its checkState on click, so you wouldn't need to click twice. I think it looks and feels better.
if my answer was helpful, mark it as correct and vote up :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and really sorry for the trouble. Also thank you for the explaination